# Exterior/wedge product of two vectors as an area?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vectors, vector-analysis

It is often said that the exterior/wedge product of two vectors represents an area, or signed area with undefined shape, and they show a picture of two vectors in 2 dimensions (could be **i** and **j**) with an exterior product that is the parallelogram spanned by the vectors, or a circle with the same area as the parallelogram, or so; and a connection is made with the usual cross product, cause both exterior and cross products have the same scalar magnitude or area. So far so good.

Now in 3 dimensions instead of **i** and **j** let's take the vectors **u**=(0.853, -0.146, 0.5) and **v**=(-0.146, 0.853, 0.5); these vectors are just the **i**, **j** rotated, so they are just unit vectors spanning a 90º angle. In regard to the cross product nothing essential has changed, it will be again a vector and its length will be the same area as it was with **i** and **j**. But according to Wikipedia (Exterior Algebra, section Cross And Triple Products) the exterior product is now:

**u** Λ **v** = (u1·v2-u2·v1)(**i** Λ **j**) + (u2·v3-u3·v2)(**j** Λ **k**) + (u3·v1-u1·v3)(**k** Λ **i**)  (giving three non-null coefficients similar to the cross product),

however this doesn't look anymore like a parallelogram/area as in the 2-dimensional case, it looks like three juxtaposed parallelograms/areas or equivalently like a parallelepiped/volume.

So with general vectors in 3 dimensions the exterior product of two vectors doesn't seem to represent an area, as is ALWAYS pictured in books and papers; or perhaps it does and I'm completely wrong and missing important details.

I've done some research but can't find the solution. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Do you know the existence of the domain called ["geometric algebra"](http://www.jaapsuter.com/geometric-algebra.pdf) that considers traditional "objects" of nD vector algebra under a very synthetic way, in particular the cross product ?...

Comment: @JeanMarie What do you mean by that it considers them under a synthetic way?

Comment: "Synthetic" in the sense that, for example one can write (it's in fact a definition) $ab = a \ . \ b  + a \wedge b$ gathering in a same formula product, dot product and wedge product...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter if you write it as $\mathbf{u} \wedge \mathbf{v}$ or multiply everything out, that bivector represents the oriented area of the parallelogram spanned by $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$. In general when you have a bivector in three dimensions you can read off a vector from the coefficients, and the bivector will represent the oriented area of a parallelogram lying in the plane with that vector as its normal.

It's only when you get to four (or more) dimensions that you can have *non-simple* bivectors, i.e., bivectors that cannot be written as the wedge product of two vectors, for example $\mathbf{e}_1 \wedge \mathbf{e}_2 + \mathbf{e}_3 \wedge \mathbf{e}_4$.

Comment: Understood. Thanks to your answer and to the comment of Jean Marie, I've done more research and been able at last to grasp the addition of bivectors. I'll try to answer my own question.

Answer (score 2):

I posted the question cause I couldn't find a visual explanation of the "area addition" in usual books and web sites. Thanks to the answer of Hans Lundmark and the comment of Jean Marie, I've done more research and been able to understand at last the addition of bivectors/exterior products/wedge products, so I'll try to visually answer my own question.

The bivector/exterior product/wedge product **u** Λ **v** of two vectors **u** and **v** is a flat signed (oriented) area of undefined shape, an instance of which is the parallelogram P that the vectors determine, see Fig.1. The perpendicular to P with the same magnitude/length as the area of P is the cross product/vector product **w**.

[image]

It happens that P is inclined, so we can't define it with just one basis bivector **i** Λ **j**, we need a special addition of three bivectors $a_{ij}$ **i** Λ **j** + $a_{ik}$ **i** Λ **k** + $a_{jk}$ **j** Λ **k**, see Fig.2, where the coefficients or areas $a_{ij}$ , $a_{ik}$ , $a_{jk}$ have the same values as the components z, y, x of the cross product **w**. Note that this similitude doesn't mean that the vector **w** could fit exactly into the "box" formed by the three bivectors in Fig.2; i.e, the "bivector box" in Fig.2 and the dotted "vector box" in Fig.1 are different, for example the horizontal area $a_{ij}$ has the same value as the vertical (not any horizontal) coordinate z of **w**.

In order to visually add the three bivectors/areas, called $a_{ij}$ , $a_{ik}$ , $a_{jk}$ from now on to simplify, we first take $a_{ij}$ and $a_{ik}$ in Fig.3 and get the dark parallelogram $a_{ij}$ + $a_{ik}$ that completes the wedge. Then we should add $a_{jk}$ , but it happens that the parallelograms $a_{ij}$ + $a_{ik}$ and $a_{jk}$ doesn't share a side, so we take advantage of the undefined shape of a bivector and we transform $a_{jk}$ into $a_{jk}$', which has the same area but shares a side with $a_{ij}$ + $a_{ik}$ , see Fig.4. Now we add them completing again the wedge, and get the final parallelogram P which is the same as in Fig.1.

Given **u** and **v**, both **u** Λ **v** and **w** = **u ⨯ v** carry the same information (the bare coefficients) in different ways. Perhaps **w** (in the form of a sum of three coordinates, the dotted box in Fig.1) is intuitively easier to visualize in space than **u** Λ **v** (in the form of a sum of three parallelograms/areas, the box in Fig.2); that's why bivectors seem to be little known. But in some special situations they could perform better than the cross product, as I've read.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community Bot :  What are exactly the parts that are unclear or that you don't understand?  I can delete my answer, no problem, but I can't make clearer the unknown things that you say are unclear.

Answer (score 1):

The exterior product of two vectors doesn't represent an simple area, but an *oriented* area. It's just that in two dimensions, this becomes a scalar since it only has one vector component (but it can still be considered oriented because if the sign of the component).

In three dimensions, an oriented are is equivalent to the combination of an area and a [normal vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) for that area. Two [bivectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector) that are the results of two different exterior products between vectors can have the same magnitude (the same area), but their normal directions can still be different (in which case the two bivectors are also different).

Just like a vector that isn't aligned with any of the basis axis will have more than one non-zero component, a bivector representing a surface that isn't aligned with two of the basis axis will also have more than one non-zero component.

In four dimensions or higher, the orientation of the area can't be described by a single normal vector; you would instead describe the orientation by two vectors that are tangent to the oriented area. This can be done in any number of dimensions but isn't necessary in fewer than four dimensions.

Note also that while the number of components of a vector in $n$-dimensional space is $n$ (or ${n\choose 1}$, if you will), the number of components of a bivector is ${n\choose 2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, so only in three dimensions do vectors and bivectors have the same number of components (which is also why it suffices to use a single vector in three dimensions to represent the orientation of a bivector; it unfortunatelly also causes vectors and bivectors to be conflated in three dimensions when they should rather be kept apart, leading to uses of the cross product where the exterior product would have been a much more natural choice). In general, a [$k$-vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivector) in $n$-dimensional space will have ${n\choose k}$ components.

As a bonus, I would like to link to [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60z_hpEAtD8), which is an excellent, short introduction to geometric algebra, and does a great job of explaining the exterior/wedge product and motivating its existence.